# Custom validation with ajax.....Here remote method is not working

Tags: validation, jquery, spring-mvc

I am using jquery.validate.js, in the code below both remote and regex works separately but when I try to integrate both then it is not working. Can anybody help me where I did wrong?

```
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#clear").click(function(){

            $("input[type=text], textarea").val("");

        });
});

function submitForm() {

    $.validator.addMethod("subTitleVal", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z\s\_,\.:;()''""]+$/.test(value); 
    }, "Enter Valid Name.");

    var validator = $("#company").validate({
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            offset = element.offset();
            error.insertBefore(element)
            error.addClass('message'); 
            error.css('position', 'absolute');
            error.css('left', offset.left + element.outerWidth());
        },
        rules : {
            name : {
                required : true,
                subTitleVal : true,
                      remote: {
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/company/getDuplicate",
                        data: {"name":name},
                        dataType : "json",
                        success:function(data){
                            /* response = ( data == true ) ? true : false; */
                            if (data.name == true)
                            {
                                message: {
                                    name: 'The username is already in use!'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
                },
        },
        errorElement : "span",
        wrapper : "span",
        messages : {
            name : {
                required : "Name Is Required",
            }
        }
    });
    if(validator.form()){ 
        $('form#company').submit(); 
        }
};

</script>

   </head>
   <body>
 <form:form commandname="company" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/company/create.action"  method="post" modelAttribute="company" name="theform">

    <label>Name:</label>
    <form:input path="name" id="name"></form:input>

    <a href="Javascript:submitForm()">Add</a>

</form:form>

</body>
```

please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your code with this

```
function submitForm() {

    $.validator.addMethod("subTitleVal", function(value, element) {
                return this.optional(element)
                        || /^[A-Za-z\s\_,\.:;()''""]+$/.test(value);
            }, "Enter Valid Name.");

    var validator = $("#company").validate({
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            offset = element.offset();
            error.insertBefore(element)
            error.addClass('message');
            error.css('position', 'absolute');
            error.css('left', offset.left + element.outerWidth());
        },
        rules : {
            name : {
                required : true,
                subTitleVal : true,
                remote : {
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/company/getDuplicate",
                    data : {
                        name: function() { return $("#name").val(); }

                    }
                }
            }
        },
        errorElement : "span",
        wrapper : "span",
        messages : {
            name : {
                required : "Name Is Required",
                remote : "Name Already Taken."
            }
        }
    });
    if (validator.form()) {
        $('form#company').submit();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method)

> The response is evaluated as JSON and must be true for valid elements,
>   and can be any false, undefined or null for invalid elements, using
>   the default message; or a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try
>   peter123 instead" to display as the error message.

So your validation url must return an appropriate value

Try

```
function submitForm() {

    $.validator.addMethod("subTitleVal", function(value, element) {
                return this.optional(element)
                        || /^[A-Za-z\s\_,\.:;()''""]+$/.test(value);
            }, "Enter Valid Name.");

    var validator = $("#company").validate({
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            offset = element.offset();
            error.insertBefore(element)
            error.addClass('message');
            error.css('position', 'absolute');
            error.css('left', offset.left + element.outerWidth());
        },
        rules : {
            name : {
                required : true,
                subTitleVal : true,
                remote : {
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/company/getDuplicate",
                    data : {
                        "name" : name
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        errorElement : "span",
        wrapper : "span",
        messages : {
            name : {
                required : "Name Is Required"
            }
        }
    });
    if (validator.form()) {
        $('form#company').submit();
    }
};
```

Comment: please see code agin. I am using remote to identify duplicate entries, from that url i am getting Boolean status(depends on data is exist or not) as of your post validation is working fine but not the duplicate entries

Comment: i wanted like,should check duplicate as well as validate using regex. i have custom method which identify duplicate.See this jQuery.validator.addMethod("uniqueName", function(name, element) {
     var response;
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/company/getDuplicate",
            data:{"name":name},
            async:false,
            success:function(data){
             response = ( data == true ) ? true : false;
            }
        })
      return response; 
 }, "Name is Already Taken");

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets are not closed properly. You have an extra `},`

Keep your code well-indented to avoid such minor mistakes in the future.

This should be your code instead:

```
function submitForm() {

    $.validator.addMethod("subTitleVal", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z\s\_,\.:;()''""]+$/.test(value);
    }, "Enter Valid Name.");

    var validator = $("#company").validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            offset = element.offset();
            error.insertBefore(element)
            error.addClass('message');
            error.css('position', 'absolute');
            error.css('left', offset.left + element.outerWidth());
        },
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                subTitleVal: true,
                remote: {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/company/getDuplicate",
                    data: {
                        "name": name
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        /* response = ( data == true ) ? true : false; */
                        if (data.name == true) {
                            message: {
                                name: 'The username is already in use!'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        },
        errorElement: "span",
        wrapper: "span",
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Name Is Required",
            }
        }
    });
    if (validator.form()) {
        $('form#company').submit();
    }
};
```

Comment: see i updated my code now, hear remote method is not working i am using this to identify duplicate entries in a form,